# Remove xml elements or py objects that have certain attribute with value

Tags: python-3.x, xml

How can I remove the SVG elements that have a "fill" attribute where its value is "none" from XML or a py object representation of XML? See examples below
E.g. Remove these from the example:

```
<path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/>
<rect fill="none" height="24" width="24"/>
```

I don't care if it's removed from the py objects or the XML itself, whichever is simpler I guess

I am using `xmltodict` to create an SVG library by reading in a bunch of SVGs in a folder and mooshing them together.

The resultant SVG XML is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <style>.icon { display: none }
            .icon:target { display: inline }</style>
    </defs>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <g class="icon" id="action.nightlight-round">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M12.01 12c0-3.57 2.2-6.62 5.31-7.87.89-.36.75-1.69-.19-1.9-1.1-.24-2.27-.3-3.48-.14-4.51.6-8.12 4.31-8.59 8.83C4.44 16.93 9.13 22 15.01 22c.73 0 1.43-.08 2.12-.23.95-.21 1.1-1.53.2-1.9-3.22-1.29-5.33-4.41-5.32-7.87z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <g class="icon" id="action.not-started">
            <g>
                <rect fill="none" height="24" width="24"/>
                <path d="M12,2C6.48,2,2,6.48,2,12c0,5.52,4.48,10,10,10s10-4.48,10-10C22,6.48,17.52,2,12,2z M11,16H9V8h2V16z M12,16V8l5,4L12,16z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

This starts off as py objects (OrderedDicts and lists) and I convert it into XML with the `xmltodict` library.

this is an example py object for the same XML above:

```
OrderedDict([('svg', OrderedDict([('@xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'), ('@xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'), ('defs', [OrderedDict([('style', '.icon { display: none }\n\t\t\t.icon:target { display: inline }')])]), ('svg', [OrderedDict([('@viewBox', '0 0 24 24'), ('g', OrderedDict([('@class', 'icon'), ('@id', 'action.nightlight-round'), ('path', [OrderedDict([('@d', 'M0 0h24v24H0V0z'), ('@fill', 'none')]), OrderedDict([('@d', 'M12.01 12c0-3.57 2.2-6.62 5.31-7.87.89-.36.75-1.69-.19-1.9-1.1-.24-2.27-.3-3.48-.14-4.51.6-8.12 4.31-8.59 8.83C4.44 16.93 9.13 22 15.01 22c.73 0 1.43-.08 2.12-.23.95-.21 1.1-1.53.2-1.9-3.22-1.29-5.33-4.41-5.32-7.87z')])])]))]), OrderedDict([('@viewBox', '0 0 24 24'), ('g', OrderedDict([('@class', 'icon'), ('@id', 'action.not-started'), ('g', OrderedDict([('rect', OrderedDict([('@fill', 'none'), ('@height', '24'), ('@width', '24')])), ('path', OrderedDict([('@d', 'M12,2C6.48,2,2,6.48,2,12c0,5.52,4.48,10,10,10s10-4.48,10-10C22,6.48,17.52,2,12,2z M11,16H9V8h2V16z M12,16V8l5,4L12,16z')]))]))]))])])]))])
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is best done with XSLT. Using XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:transform 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="3.0">
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="svg:*[@fill='none']"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

(It can also be done in XSLT 1.0, it's just a bit more verbose. Replace the `xsl:mode` declaration with an identity template.)